# Mysql avoid duplicate entry error in insert select

Tags: mysql, select, insert

I have a movie recommendation website and I want to change the categories where the films are now included.

For the moment, I need the old categories and the new ones to coexist in my mysql database.

So in the table that relates categories and movies I have:

```
id_category (PK)| id_movie (PK) | category_name
12 | 7822 | japanese horror
13 | 4563 | new fantasy
202 | 7822 | horror 
303 | 4563 | fantasy
```

To include the new categories I have executed:

```
INSERT INTO category_movie (id_category, id_movie, category_name)
SELECT 202,id_movie, 'horror' FROM category_movie WHERE id_category = 12;
```

and so on.  This is what I need and it works great.

But I find this case:

For the category "action comedy" with id 39 I want to insert a new id 2122 with the name "comedy" and for the category "classic comedy" with id 58 I also want to insert it again as "comedy" with id 2122.

But if I use the above:

```
INSERT INTO category_movie (id_category, id_movie, category_name)
SELECT 2122,id_movie, 'comedy' FROM category_movie WHERE id_category = 39;
INSERT INTO category_movie (id_category, id_movie, category_name)
SELECT 2122,id_movie, 'comedy' FROM category_movie WHERE id_category = 58;
```

I get this error:

```
Error Code: 1062. Duplicate entry '2122-581' for key 'PRIMARY'
```

Movie with id 581 can belong to more than one category.

What can I do to avoid getting this error?

Thank you very much

Comment: By the looks of it, you have a movie with id = 581 which already has both categories 39 and 58, causing you to add comedy twice. You could use an `INSERT IGNORE` for your 2nd query to ignore the duplicate row

Comment: *What can I do to avoid getting this error?* The only way to avoid PK duplicate violation is to alter or to remove PK. As a temporary solution you may store a list of categories in `category_name` column in CSV (or JSON) format.

Comment: I do not understand the point of the 2nd insert ... select ... It would create **an exact duplicate** of the first `2122,id_movie, 'comedy'` record. I think @Akina 's suggestion is incorrect, since getting rid of the PK would just enable you to create a duplicate record. To be honest, it would be easier if you provided more background to this problem because this hole insert ... select ... thing looks very strange (you could do a simple insert without the select part) and I do not understand its use here.

Comment: Basically, OP wants to add the comedy category to all movies which already have the category 39 and all those who have 58, that's why there are 2 inserts. The issue comes from the fact that these two groups of movies have some overlap (at the very least, the movie 581 is in both)

Comment: @Shadow OP explicitly **wants** to create duplicated row.

Comment: Are you trying to create a category - subcategory structure here where both `classic comedy` and `action comedy` maps to a `comedy` main category? In this case you need to store the parent category id along with the current category id in the same record. There would still be only one `comedy` record, it is the subcategory record that would have to refer to the new parent category.

Comment: I don't understand why this table stores both `id_category` and `category_name`. Does it is possible that the same value of `id_category` may match to different values in `category_name` or backward? if not then `id_category` and `category_name` must be moved to separate table, and only `id_category` stored in current table. PS. If some `id_category` value always matches to the same `category_name` value in all rows then simply use INSERT IGNORE.

Comment: @Akina I strongly doubts that's what OP wants. "Movie with id 581 can belong to more than one category." is what the OP perceives to be the issue, while the problem comes from the fact that OP accidentaly tries to add the same category to the same movie, twice

Comment: @Akina the OP may want a duplicate record, but that makes absolutely no sense in an rdbms, since it will not be able to differentiate between the two records. So, this is when we challenge the OP on the requirements.

Comment: @Shadow I agree that the task is unclear now... and only OP may clarify it. Let's wait...

Comment: Where does it say OP wants duplicate records? I'm not sure we're reading the same question. From my point of view, OP asked: here is my situation, here are the queries I run, and here is the error, how do I prevent it. And this is what my first comment addresses. There is no talk of wanting duplicates, or wanting to improve the database's structure